# Why isn't the "\t" escaping this PHP date format?

Tags: php, date, escaping

Here's the date.
Everything is being escaped but the t in "\a\t". Anybody know why?

```
date("M m\, Y \a\t g\:ia", $s->post_date);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`"\t"` is a escape sequence for the horizontal tab character.

Use `'\t'` or `"\\t"`

Single-quoted strings interpret `\` literally, which I'd recommend for your use case. Otherwise you have to escape the `\` character to have it interpreted literally.

In PHP's case, the `\` preceding an invalid escape sequence inside a double-quoted string also gets interpreted literally. I'd rather avoid this behavior, following the principle of least surprise.

ps. (thanks to @IMSoP) There are two cases where `\`s are not interpreted literally inside single-quoted strings:

- Doubling  backslashes is still possible but optional. E.g.: `'\\hi' === '\hi'`
- The string delimiter character must be escaped inside of a string literal. E.g.: `'\'' === "'"`

Still, single-quoted strings are less surprising in that `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v`, `\040` and similar result in the actual sequence of characters inside of the string literal instead of these being interpreted as escape sequences.

Doubling all backslashes that must be interpreted literally is also a sturdy option that works with both double and single quoted strings as well.

Comment: One slight nit-pick: single-quoted strings interpret `\\` literally **except for the sequences `\'` and `\\`**. This has the odd effect that `'\t'` and `'\\t'` are actually the same string (one `\`), as are `'\\\t'` and `'\\\\t'` (two backslashes).

Comment: @IMSoP The "\" character inside comments' inline-code is terribly bugged here unfortunately. `:(` But I understood what you meant. `=]`

Comment: Yeah, just realised that; backslash escapes are always a pain. Key point is, they can be just as surprising inside single-quotes as double-quotes in PHP, since doubling them is still possible but optional. I would advise always doubling them, ugly though it looks.

Comment: For reference, [here's what I was trying to post in that comment](http://pastebin.com/wWYrwKva).

Comment: @IMSoP Oh double escaping inside single-quoted strings, that's something I haven't tried. Thanks for the input, I'll add it to the answer after I run a couple more tests. And yeah, these escapes are always a pain. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yeah, as soon as backslash-quote has a meaning, backslash-backslash comes into play to avoid that meaning, and you're into doubling territory. In Bash, for instance, you simply cannot include a single-quote in a single-quoted string, so backslash is unambiguous. I am, however, perversely proud of a piece of code, briefly installed on production servers, which nested so many string formations it contained 15 consecutive backslashes...

Comment: @IMSoP 15 consecutive backslashes typed and maintained by hand? That's madness. `:D`