# PHP add the word 'at' in Date()

Tags: php

```
 $dateFormatted = date("l, M j g:i a", strtotime($day .' '. $preferTime )      );
```

very simple but can't find it

i want to word 'at' between my month and time, obviously 'a' and 't' are reserved. What can i do?

Should i just do this? there must be a smarter way

```
$dateFormatted1 = date("l, M j ", strtotime($day .' '. $preferTime )      );
$dateFormatted2 = date("g:i a", strtotime($day .' '. $preferTime )      );
echo $dateFormmated1 . 'at' $dateFormatted2;
```

Comment: http://php.net/date#example-2294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the characters with backslashes.

With single quotes you need to escape the special characters (but not the tab):

```
date('l, M j \a\t g:i a');
```

With double quotes you do need to escape the tab also (so double backslash):

```
date("l, M j \a\\t g:i a");
```

Comment: You need to double-escape `t` because `\t` is a tab.

Comment: Also, / is a slash, \ is a backslash.

Comment: thanks i tried \ and it didn't work i didn't realize i had to double \\ the t

Comment: on a side note is there a smarter way to change am to a.m.? i just did a string replace

Comment: You only need to escape the backslash in double-quoted strings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926999/why-isnt-the-t-escaping-this-php-date-format

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
$dateFormatted = date("l, M j \a\\t g:i a", strtotime($day .' '. $preferTime )      );
```